# Encoding error in SPARQL result set when downloaded after Upgrade to GraphDB 10

Tags: encoding, sparql, rdf, graphdb

since the Upgrade to 10.0 there is an encoding error when downloading a SPARQL result. The error occurs when I concat a hard coded string in the result set:
[image]

becomes

[image]

in a CSV (and any other format) result when downloaded. It is displayed correctly in the GraphDB environment.

Is there any workaround or is this just a newly introduced bug?

Comment: GraphDB Support confirmed it is a bug that was introduced in GraphDB 10.